# How can I print all my docker container without losing the column headers?

Tags: docker, awk

The command `docker container ls -a` lists all the docker containers, that are registered on your system (started and stopped ones), in that format:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                      PORTS                                                                                      NAMES
1e1cabc6ad32   hello-world              "/hello"                 7 days ago    Exited (0) 7 days ago                                                                                                  abcdef
```

Furthermore I am aware of docker's `format` command:

```
docker container ls -a --format '{{.Names}}'
```

This one lists only the image names, which is what I try to achieve, however I do not want to lose those column headers. So I tried playing around with *awk*:

```
docker container ls -a | awk '{print $2}'
```

This one for example lists me the image types, but the column becomes `ID` because the first column has the heading `CONTAINER ID` with a white space in it.

The longer the table gets, the more mistakes get in with this easy awk command.
I noticed that all entries inside a column have only 1 whitespace, but the separators between the columns have 3 white spaces.

So my questions is how I can get an array by awk that separates me the entries like that?
I guess there is something already asked like this, but I couldn't find anything since I am not really familiar with awk.

Comment: If you need to do that much processing on the output, maybe writing a script using a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) in a more full-featured language is a better choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the [table](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) keyword/directive to include the headers. For example:

```
$ docker container ls -a --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}'
CONTAINER ID   NAMES
9b9fce78d02d   upbeat_goodall
f9a1b191eecd   xenodochial_mclaren
ea72b3b4a8de   exciting_gould
990405ea87d1   strange_colden
bb2cffd1f514   youthful_agnesi
58e684d6d61f   brave_darwin
```

If the output needs to be parsed, consider instead writing JSON, which can be easily parsed using [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq#jq) on the command-line for example:

```
docker container ls -a --format='{{json .}}' | jq -r '.'
```

Comment: That's really nice. Have overlooked this one so far. I am still curious of an awk solution though as this tool seems to be usable universally. As my question goals on docker, I will accept this one later. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It can be done with AWK, but it's a bit more (or a lot more) work parsing fields of fixed width, which is the output of `docker container ls -a`. Plus there's no guarantee your fields will have the same fieldwidths on subsequent runs (e.g. you might start a new container with a much longer image name compared to existing names).

Comment: Note that even the formatted docker output is not actually tab-separated, so parsing it using AWK would also require some work. See: `docker container ls -a --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}' | cat -A`

Comment: OK I have several image names with long PORT colmuns (see in my example output) and I think, that there are never the 3 whitespaces. So I thought I can make the 3 white spaces to my separator.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Avoid parsing this with AWK. I see that it's possible to output in [json format](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/), which can be parsed easily using [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq#jq). For example: `docker container ls -a --format='{{json .}}' | jq -r '.'`

Comment: your concerns are justified probaly however I will keep the awk command in my mind for easy tinkering e.g. it might work with programs like netstat, too. Being aware of course that might break in any production code relatively easy

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the question, that the fields are separated by more than 3 spaces, below is an `awk` solution.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[[:space:]]{3,}"; OFS="\t"}{print $1OFS$NF}' <(docker container  ls -a)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working perfectly for my needs. However, Steve's answer is closer to the questions since I haven't generalized it and I asked specially for docker's ls.

Comment: Be aware some fields may contain trailing whitespace